# Biztalk ReceiveLocation and SendPort status checking

Tags: biztalk

Sometimes our Biztalk server receivelocation and sendport will be disabled due to cannot access the shared path specified in the receivelocation or sendport after retrying up to the threshold value.

But unfortunately there is no error event raised in event log or email sent out when the receivelocation or sendport is disabled. Therefore, no support staff can be alerted.

Therefore, we would like to know any method such that system will raise error event or send email when one of the receivelocation or sendport is disabled?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's my experiance that BizTalk will log an Event when a Receive Location shuts itself down.  It's the one where it notes the error threshold or some such.

You can capture that with SCOM or any other menagement tool and take action, such as send an alert.

Additionally, BizTalk 360 can do theat and a lot of other BizTalk specific monitoring tasks.